# Wrong handles at opening existing semaphores

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to control some processes with semaphores. Therefore I have written this class:

extract from ClassSem.hpp

```
void ClassSem::createSemaphore(char p_semaphoreName[32])
{
#ifdef MODE_WIN
   this->hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL,0L,2L,p_semaphoreName);
   printf("create Bez. %s - SemID: %i\n",p_semaphoreName,(int)hSemaphore);

   if(this->hSemaphore == NULL)
   {
      this->errnoRet = (uint32_t)GetLastError();
   }
#endif // MODE_WIN
}


void ClassSem::openSemaphore(char p_semaphoreName[32])
{
#ifdef MODE_WIN
   this->hSemaphore = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS,TRUE,p_semaphoreName);

   printf("open Bez. %s - SemID: %i\n",p_semaphoreName,(int)hSemaphore);

   if(this->hSemaphore == NULL)
   {
      this->errnoRet = (uint32_t)GetLastError();
   }
#endif // MODE_WIN
}


void ClassSem::waitOnSemaphore ()
{
#ifdef MODE_WIN
printf("wait Sem %i - ",(int)this->hSemaphore);
   WaitForSingleObject(this->hSemaphore,LONG_MAX);
#endif // MODE_WIN
}
```

One Prozess will create 12 semaphores with `ClObj[n].createSemaphore(semaphoreName[n])`. At another process I open it with `l_obj.createSemaphore(semaphoreName)`. 
But if I run the processes this happens:

main process:

```
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0000 - SemID: 1788
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0001 - SemID: 1784
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0002 - SemID: 1780
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0003 - SemID: 1776
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0004 - SemID: 1772
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0005 - SemID: 1768
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0006 - SemID: 1764
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0007 - SemID: 1760
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0008 - SemID: 1756
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0009 - SemID: 1752
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0010 - SemID: 1748
create name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0011 - SemID: 1744
```

one other process

```
open name Global\NSemaphoreProzessID_0010 - SemID: 1788
```

If I use `l_obj.createSemaphore(semaphoreName)` more than once, the IDs goes downward the upper list. Why is it so?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: What were you expecting, and why?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, why are you creating semaphores in the global kernel object namespace vs. the session namespace?

Comment: You seem to ascribe some deep significance to a numeric value of a kernel object handle. There is none. A handle is only meaningful in a process that created it; another process may have a handle to the same object but with a different numeric value, and/or a handle with the same numeric value referring to a completely unrelated object. Further, every time you call `CreateSemaphore` or `OpenSemaphore` with the same name, you create a new handle to the same object; all these handles will, naturally, have distinct numeric values (within a given process).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik And how I can check, if the Handle on both sides the same?

Comment: Why do you want to check that? Do you have any reason to doubt that creating an object with the same name twice gives you two handles to the same object? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It was only thinking about safety

Comment: What dangers do you envision, that you want to protect against?

Comment: I thought it could be possible, that a wrong process will controlled by the semaphore. That could be critical in the desired application. But I think, you're right. It's enough to do it the way as described above by you.

Comment: You should, however, make sure that you will not run into inadvertent name collisions. The name you chose is likely to be used by others. I would recommend using the string representation of a GUID instead (possibly appending a serial number if you require one).

Comment: If you are concerned about security, then you shouldn't be creating unsecured kernel objects in a global namespace. You are inviting denial-of-service attacks. Any process can indeed open a handle to your semaphore, then just lock it and never release.

Comment: If you are concerned that someone pre-creates a semaphore with your name, and your `CreateSemaphore` call opens their handle instead of creating a new one, check with `GetLastError` after the call. It will return 0 if you got a new semaphore, and `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if you got an existing one.